# Bootstrap nav-justified failed

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, web

I'm trying to use Bootstrap to build a webpage. I created a navigation bar using the class `nav-justified`. Then I run it on safari and chrome, but this problem occurs: 
When i drag the window to resize it small and then resize to the original size, these tabs stack together. Why did it happen and how can I avoid this? This is bootstrap V3.1.1.

Original one:
[image: correct one]
Stacked one:
[image: stack together]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">8</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. To check responsiveness, use mozilla and short cut: CTRL + SHIFT + M. You can play around with different screen resolution.
2. Please place jQuery before Bootstrap.js
3. After you resize to original size, have you refresh the page?

Comment: I don't see it: http://jsbin.com/pelepuyu/1

Comment: Never mind... just saw it in Safari.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's probably just a bootstrap's bug in safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-safari-percentages) make a mention of a [bug in Safari](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9282) regarding its inability to properly deal with decimal percentages for the column-grid.

The bug report has a few anecdotes of how people <strike>solved</strike> found a way around this issue.